# Why isn't RelayCommand called?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand

I have the following in my ViewModel:

```
public MyViewModel() {
  CloseCommend = new RelayCommand(closeWindow);
}

public RelayCommand CloseCommend;
private void closeWindow() {
  Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button ... Command="{Binding CloseCommend}"/>
```

I see the ViewModel constructor is initialized so the binding should be there. But when I click the close button, nothing happens. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from a field definition to a property definition:

```
public RelayCommand CloseCommand { get; set; }
```

**Why:**

Fields are typically, not bindable.  Check out the [Binding Sources Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as
>   indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object. The binding
>   engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties.
>   Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a
>   registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.
>
> For more information about how to implement a class that can serve as
>   a binding source, see Implementing a Class for the Binding Source
>   later in this topic.

Under the "**Other Characteristics**" section:

> You cannot bind to public fields.